# why java has no StringBufferOutputStream

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, stringbuffer

So if there is a java.io.StringBufferInputStream, you would think that there would be a StringBufferOutputStream.

Any ideas as to why there isn't??

Likewise,there is also a SequenceInputStream but no SequenceOutputStream.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that someone never got around to making a `StringBufferOutputStream` in Java 1.0 since the product was somewhat "rushed to market."  By the time Java 1.1 rolled around and people actually understood that readers and writers were for characters, and inputstreams and outputstreams were for bytes, the whole concept of using streams for strings was realized to be wrong, so the `StringBufferInputStream` was rightly deprecated, with no chance *ever* of a partner coming along.

A `SequenceInputStream` is a nice way to read from a bunch of streams all concatenated together, but it doesn't make much sense to write a single stream to multiple streams.  Well, I suppose you *could* make sense of this if you wanted to write a large stream into multiple partitions (reminds me of Hadoop here).  It's just not common enough to be in a *standard* library.  A complication here would be that you would need to specify the size of each output partition and would really only make sense for *files* (which can have names with increasing suffixes, perhaps), and so would not generalize into arbitrary output streams in a nice manner.

Answer (score 2):

StringBufferInputStream is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html), because bytes and characters are not the same thing.  The correct classes to use for this are [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) and [StringWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html).

If you think about it, there is no way to make a SequenceOutputStream work.  SequenceInputStream reads from the first stream until it is exhausted, then reads from the next stream.  Since an OutputStream is never exhausted (unless, say, it happens to be connected to a socket whose peer closes the connection), how would a SequenceOutputStream class know when to move on to the next stream?

Answer (score 0):

StringBufferInputStream has long been depreciated. 
Use StringReader and StringWriter.